# How to merge objects inside array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

After aggregation I came to a point of having this data , but I am stuck at point where I want to merge all objects inside **games** array and make a **player** array having objects of players.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("601..."),
    "games" : [ 
        {
            "location" : ["Mumbai"],
            "game" : ObjectId("5fe..."),
            "player" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ff2....."),
                "name" : "Tom"
            },

        }, 
        {
            "location" : ["Mumbai"],
            "game" : ObjectId("5fe..."),
            "player" : {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ff1..."),
                "name" : "Sunil"
            },
        }
}
```

Desired Output :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("601..."),
    "games" : [ 
        {
            "location" : ["Mumbai"],
            "game" : ObjectId("5fe..."),
            "player" : [
                {
                 "_id" : ObjectId("5ff2....."),
                 "name" : "Tom"
                },
                {
                 "_id" : ObjectId("5ff1..."),
                 "name" : "Sunil"
                }
            ]

        }
}
```

Comment: Before that, do the `location` and `game` need to be concerned when merging object for `player`?

Comment: @YongShun hey yes ! we want location and game in the games array . location is same in all objects and game is the id , on basis of which we want to merge the objects ( as i have shown in desired output )